# Why am I getting this invalid parse?

Tags: php, json, ajax, sqlite

I have an Ajax function to load all columns names and their values via php as follow:

> PHP SIDE:

```
$res = $db->query($stmt);
$rsltz= array();
while ($row = $res->fetchArray(SQLITE3_ASSOC)) {
    foreach ($row as $colonne => $valeur) {
      $rsltz[$colonne] = isset($valeur) ? $valeur : ""; 
    }
}
header('Content-type: application/json');
echo (json_encode($rsltz));
```

> AJAX FUNCTION:

```
function jet(a,b,c){
$.ajax({
        type: 'POST',   
        cache: false,           
        url: 'builder.php',
        data:  { typ:a, lg:b ,menu:c},
         success: function(result) { 
             if(typeof(result) === "string") {
                $('#par').after(result);
              } else {
                //JSON hier comes a loop to display key=>val
                var pars = JSON.parse(result); 
             $('#par').after(pars.datasrc);
              }          
        },
        error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
        alert(jqXHR+'\n'+textStatus+'\n'+ errorThrown);
        }
});
}
```

I have this error:
[image]

here the json.encoded result :

**{"id":"510","menu":"regis","taketo":"regis1","auth":"ALL"}**

I do appreciate any help ☺.

Comment: Are you using an old Internet Explorer as a test browser here? Yikes :-) I’d recommend you use a more modern browser, and then check what the browser console has to say. Also check what the actual response to the request was, in the network panel.

Comment: yes it's an old IE browser.. Is there a way to let it happen right ?

Comment: Let what happen right? Development? Yes, don’t use an old IE. The AJAX request/JSON response? Yes, by finding out what the error actually is first of all. How to do that, you already got hints on that.

Comment: So this error is just because of the OLD character of my browser?!.. no way!

Comment: No, I did not say that. But the debug tools in old IE are quite terrible, and finding out what actually went wrong here, is going to be much easier in a current browser, that offers proper dev tools.

Comment: here the json.encoded  result : {"id":"510","menu":"regis","taketo":"regis1","auth":"ALL"} and unfortunately I can't run this in a newer IE.

Comment: Check if this jquery version is compatible with you browser. You may need to use an older jquery version or use pure javascript instead.

Comment: It is hard to figure out what exactly those old IE error messages are actually referring to. It says something on line 28, character 6 was the problem here. The JSON you have shown doesn’t appear to have that many lines, and the error message is referring to home.php anyway. So go check what is there in that position. (In the output of the script, not the PHP code.) _“and unfortunately I can't run this in a newer IE.”_ - and you don’t have Chrome or Firefox available either, to _test_ this in at least?

Comment: `I can't run this in a newer IE`...then try a totally different browser, just for testing. or run on more recent machine (even virtual machine) with a newer version. Even IE11's tools are not brilliant though, compared to Chrome, Edge or Firefox. Older IEs were not just designed to cope with the complexity of modern script based websites. P.S. Why are you running **such** an old version? That operating system should have been upgraded or removed a _long_ time ago. That's the real solution here. You say "can't"...but why not exactly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We don't have to re-parse what is already parsed! The response (result in Ajax function) IS already parsed. So just use it as it is:

```
var pars = JSON.parse(result); 
$('#par').after(pars.datasrc);
```

has to be replaced with

```
$('#par').after(result.datasrc);
```

Thank you guys.